Show that $g(k) = -(k-A)(k+B)$ is the unique solution for the $g(k) = g(k-1)/2 + g(k+1)/2 + 1, -B < k < A$ equation when $g(-B) = g(A) = 0$
Show that $g(k) = -(k-A)(k+B)$ is the unique solution for the $g(k) = g(k-1)/2 + g(k+1)/2 + 1, -B < k < A$ equation when $g(-B)=g(A)=0$.
My textbook finds the solution $g(k) = -(k-A)(k+B)$ by making an educated guess that $g$ must be a second-order polynomial over the integers based on the fact that the equation can be rewritten as $\Delta^2 g(k-1)/2 = -1, -B < k < A$ and that the coefficient of $k^2$ must be -1, finally also considering that the function should be 0 at $A,-B$. And then we plug into the equation and see that the equation holds. But while this is a very nice guess, it doesn't prove that the solution is unique.
Some simple observations: if $g_1,g_2$ are solutions for this equation then $g_1-g_2$ is a solution for the corresponding homogenous equation. Though in general the homogeneous equation's solutions are infinite, with the boundary conditions it might be unique. Also if we consider specific sets of functions it might be easier to show the uniqueness of the solution over those sets (e.g. over 2nd order polynomials). But I want a proof for the general case too.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

You're on the right track! Let $ G = g_1 - g_2$. Hint: Show that $G(k) - G(k-1) = G(k+1) - G(k)$, then use $G(-B) = 0, G(A) = 0 $, to conclude that $G (k)  = 0  $.

Oh, it is implied by the second difference of $G(k)$ being 0. Then $\Delta G(k-1) = -G(A-1) = const; G(A-1)-G(A-2)=-G(A-1) \implies G(A-2) = 2G(A-1);$ similarly $G(A-3) = 3G(A-1) \dots$ and finally $0=G(-B)=(A+B)G(A-1) \implies G(A-1) = 0 \implies G(k)=const \implies G(k)=0$. Thank you!!
